# On Google Form submit show a link to download your formatted response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a form that once filled in adds the response to the spreadsheet. I have also a script that takes your response and converts your info into md format. I would like the user once the form has been submitted on "Thank you page" display a link to download their response in md format.
Have no idea how to save the formatted response to Drive I believe and how to display the link to download this file. Any help/examples appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See below a sample how to

- convert a form response into an html document
- save the document on drive and obtain a download link
- include the download link into the confirmation message shown to the submitters on form submit

> To convert the form response to md instead of html, you need to
>   either write a manual function or use a third-party API

Sample:

```
function myFunction() {  
 var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
 var length= form.getResponses().length;
 var lastResponse=  form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses();
 var html="<html><body><table>";
 for(var i=0;i<lastResponse.length;i++){
    html+="<tr><td>"+lastResponse[i].getItem().getTitle()+"</td><td>"+lastResponse[i].getResponse()+"</td></tr>";
  }
 html+="</table></body></html>";
 var id=DriveApp.createFile("response"+length+".html", html).getId();
 var url=Drive.Files.get(id).webContentLink;
 form.setConfirmationMessage("Thank you filling out this form. This is the download link to your form response in html. Please wait 30 seconds before downloading, while the data is still being written into the file. "+url);
}
```

> To make this script work
>
> - Bind an onFormSubmit [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to your function
> - [Enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)

Useful references:

- [setConfirmationMessage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setconfirmationmessagemessage)
- [getResponses](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getresponses)
- [createFile](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfilename,-content)
- [webContentLink](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)